# Geth keeps changing coinbase / miner account and stops working. (POA Network)

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-debugging, poa, geth-clique

I have set up a Geth POA network of 2 nodes on different cloud instances. Network was running good for 2 months but now suddenly it's getting connections from unknown peers and mining stops working.

Geth Command:

```
geth --datadir ethdata/ --syncmode 'full' --port 30312 --rpc --rpcaddr '0.0.0.0' --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain '<URL1>,<URL2>' --rpcapi 'personal,db,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,admin' --ws --wsport 8546 --wsapi 'eth,net,web3' --wsorigins '<URL1>' --networkid <NETWORKID> --gasprice '1' --unlock <ACCOUNT1> --password pass.txt --mine --etherbase <ACCOUNT1> --allow-insecure-unlock --nat extip:<NODEIP> --nodiscover --netrestrict <NODE2IP>/32
```

Error Logs:

```
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:19.001]  mined potential block                  number=394283 hash="2ef239…81cd72"
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:19.002] Commit new mining work                   number=394284 sealhash="3377da…5031cd" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="318.567µs"
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:19.002] Signed recently, must wait for others
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:29.002] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed="442.732µs" mgasps=0.000 number=394284 hash="0612d1…139ef9" dirty=0.00B
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:29.003]  block reached canonical chain          number=394277 hash="825454…683852"
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:29.003] Commit new mining work                   number=394285 sealhash="f90c28…da2cd8" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="268.822µs"
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:39.000] Successfully sealed new block            number=394285 sealhash="f90c28…da2cd8" hash="7f408c…1fe2df" elapsed=9.997s
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:39.001] Signed recently, must wait for others
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:39.000]  mined potential block                  number=394285 hash="7f408c…1fe2df"
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:39.002] Commit new mining work                   number=394286 sealhash="190914…a34e63" uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=1.583ms
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:43.852] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1
0|ethNode1  | ERROR[10-02|21:10:43.854] Etherbase account unavailable locally    err="unknown account"
0|ethNode1  | WARN [10-02|21:10:43.854] Served miner_start                       conn=217.227.191.41:61800 reqid=1643 t=2.034872ms err="signer missing: unknown account"
0|ethNode1  | WARN [10-02|21:10:44.863] Gas estimation capped by limited funds   original=8000000 balance=98712 sent=78962 gasprice=1 fundable=19750
0|ethNode1  | WARN [10-02|21:10:44.864] Served eth_sendTransaction               conn=217.227.191.41:61805 reqid=1125 t=3.726913ms err="gas required exceeds allowance (19750)"
0|ethNode1  | WARN [10-02|21:10:45.755] Served eth_sendTransaction               conn=217.227.191.41:61807 reqid=831  t=4.255632ms err="authentication needed: password or unlock"
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:49.002] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed="301.13µs"  mgasps=0.000 number=394286 hash="5ae579…8ae413" dirty=0.00B
0|ethNode1  | INFO [10-02|21:10:54.250] Deep froze chain segment                 blocks=6 elapsed=7.777ms     number=304285 hash="2951e1…0aa545"
```

Connection from IP Address "217.227.191.41" seems to be from an unknown node. I've set `--nodiscover` as well as `--netrestrict`. Also blocked the IP address from Firewall using command:

```
ufw deny from 217.227.191.41 to any
```

But still the issue keeps happening and when I reload geth command, it works for a minute but same issue happens again. I'm also blocking RPC access as you can see in the GETH command. How do I prevent incoming connection that changes my miner account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some private discussion with the author, but it is related due to the full access to the API's via HTTP, which a bot changed the miner address.
So I would sum it up as this:
Do NOT leave Ethereum nodes with all RPC API's open to the public.
(If it wasn't you, then check what can be used to change it.)